# How to overwrite a model's save method to fill a field upon model instance saving

Tags: python, django

In the model below, I have added `file_name` field to store just the filename.

I have overwritten the save method to fill this field upon saving, but the field is still empty after uploading the file through admin panel. Even if I put a print statement in the save method, it will not print the file name.

Migrations are applied.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class DataFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='data files')
    file_name = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    uploaded_at = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{os.path.basename(self.file.path)}, uploaded at: {str(self.uploaded_at)})'

    def __save__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.file_name = os.path.basename(self.file.name)
        super(DataFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: use `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` ....

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects